# "Undefined index" error in AJAX POST request because $_POST is coming up empty

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, mysqli

I'm currently getting an "Undefined index" error after trying to send data from a JavaScript file to PHP via an AJAX POST request - **$_POST is coming up empty**. Bearing in mind that I have explored all other Stack Overflow questions about this subject to no avail, here's what's happening:

I have a questionnaire - answers to this questionnaire are saved in an array called "all_answers". When I press my questionnaire's "Finish" button, I call a function named "saveAnswersInDatabase()" that basically makes an AJAX request of the POST type. Along with that POST request, I send some data, which are the answers to my questionnaire that I store in the previously mentioned "all_answers" array.

This POST request is made to a PHP file called "questionnaire_php", in which I access the `$_POST` superglobal to first determine what action was requested, and then I do an SQL query so as to `INSERT` the answers to my questionnaire in a 'answer' table of my database.

I'm currently getting an error `Undefined index: requested_action` error.

I have tried, to no avail, to:

1. Add a `dataType` of `json` and `text` to my AJAX POST request;
2. Have all `key : value` pairs of the `data` field of my AJAX POST request be surrounded by single and double-quotes;

Here's the code.

HTML:

```
    <!-- Questionnaire's conclusion -->
    <div class="row" id="conclusion" style="display: none;">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
                    <h6><small class="text-muted">Thank you for successfully completing this questionnaire. You may review your answers by going to the EmoJar page and selecting this content's corresponding circle.</small></h6>

                    <!-- 'Finish' button -->
        <div class="text-center">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" id="questionnaire-conclusion-finish-button" onclick="saveAnswersInDatabase()"><i class="fa fa-check icons-style"></i> Finish</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
    function saveAnswersInDatabase() {
            // We prepare an AJAX request to save the answers to our questionnaire in the 'answer' table of our 'm4wb' database
            $.ajax({
                    // 'type' determines our request's type ('GET' or 'POST')
            type: "POST",
            // 'url' determines where our request will go to (e.g., a server), or through (e.g., a file)
            url: "php/questionnaire_php.php",
            // 'data' determines what data is to be sent along with our request
            data: {
                "requested_action": "save_answers",
                "question_1": all_answers[0],
                "question_1_1": all_answers[1],
                "question_2": all_answers[2],
                "question_2_1": all_answers[3],
                "question_3": all_answers[4],
                "question_3_1": all_answers[5],
                "bar_chart_colors": all_answers[6],
                "question_4": all_answers[7],
                "question_5": all_answers[8],
                "question_6": all_answers[9],
                "question_6_1": all_answers[10]
            },
            // 'success' determines what happens if our request is successfully fulfilled
            success: function() {
                console.log("The request was successfully fulfilled.");
            },
            // 'error' determines what happens if our request is not successfully fulfilled
            error: function() {
                console.log("The request could not be fulfilled.");
            }
        });
    }
```

PHP:

```
    <?php
        /* Connection data */

        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $databasename = "m4wb";

        /* Connection attempt */

        $database_connection = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $databasename);

        /* Connection verification */

        if ($database_connection) {
            echo "Connected to database.";
        } else {
            echo "Not connected to database.";
        }

        /* Requested action */

        $requested_action = $_POST["requested_action"]; // '$_POST' is an array that stores all information sent in a 'POST' request
        echo $requested_action;

        /* Requested action verification */

        // If a request to save the answers to our questionnaire was made, (...)
        if ($requested_action == "save_answers") {
            // (...) we get the data that was sent along with the request, (...)
            $question_1       = $_POST["question_1"];
            $question_1_1     = $_POST["question_1_1"];
            $question_2       = $_POST["question_2"];
            $question_2_1     = $_POST["question_2_1"];
            $question_3       = json_encode($_POST["question_3"]); // We can't directly store arrays in a database, so we use 'json_encode()' to turn the array into a string
            $question_3_1     = $_POST["question_3_1"];
            $bar_chart_colors = json_encode($_POST["bar_chart_colors"]); // We can't directly store arrays in a database, so we use 'json_encode()' to turn the array into a string
            $question_4       = json_encode($_POST["question_4"]); // We can't directly store arrays in a database, so we use 'json_encode()' to turn the array into a string
            $question_5       = $_POST["question_5"];
            $question_6       = $_POST["question_6"];
            $question_6_1     = $_POST["question_6_1"];
            echo $question_1, $question_1_1, $question_2, $question_2_1, $question_3, $question_3_1, $bar_chart_colors, $question_4, $question_5, $question_6, $question_6_1;

            // (...) we prepare our query, (...)
            $query = "INSERT INTO answer ('ID', 'USER_ID', 'CONTENT_ID', 'Q_ONE', 'Q_ONE_ONE', 'Q_TWO', 'Q_TWO_ONE', 'Q_THREE', 'Q_THREE_ONE', 'BAR_CHART_COLORS', 'Q_FOUR', 'Q_FIVE', 'Q_SIX', 'Q_SIX_ONE') VALUES ('1', '1', '1', '$question_1', '$question_1_1', '$question_2', '$question_2_1', '$question_3', '$question_3_1', '$bar_chart_colors', '$question_4', '$question_5', '$question_6', '$question_6_1')";

            // (...) we execute the query, we save its result ('TRUE' or 'FALSE'), (...)
            $query_result = mysqli_query($database_connection, $query);
            echo $query_result;

            // (...) we commit the current transaction, (...)
            mysqli_commit($database_connection);

            // (...) we close our database connection, (...)
            mysqli_close($database_connection);

            // (...) and we exit this PHP script
            exit("Exited!");
        }

        var_dump($_POST);

        exit("Exited!");

    ?>
```

I just get the aforementioned error, and I have no idea as to why. Any help is welcome! Thanks in advance.

PS: I know I can be a victim of injection, but that is to be addressed later.

**EDIT: I came upon this problem after realizing the INSERT INTO query I make in the PHP file didn't actually result in any added data to the table I want to INSERT new data INTO. I quickly found out that $_POST was empty!**

Comment: When you open Developer tools -> Networking and do your request, then do you see variables being sent?

Comment: @WKoppel I don't see anything besides the error. The $_POST array is coming up empty (array(0)) when I do var_dump($_POST), which probably means the problem is in my JavaScript code. But I can't honestly tell, I'm a server-side-stuff newbie.

Comment: Are you sure you've need to `echo $requested_action;` ?

Comment: @OlegNurutdinov I'm just doing it so I can see where my code breaks! I know the query I make in my PHP code isn't working because there's no data in the 'answer' table I refer to in the INSERT INTO query.

Comment: if you think your error in js than try to debug code. Print all_answer in js. It might contain some undefined data

Comment: @Vivek, if the user doesn't answer any question, the "all_answers" array keeps an empty string of that answer. I have no undefined data in my array.

Comment: well your code looks fine. All you could do now is try to debug. Also try with full url including http. To debug, you can send just one data at a time. For ex just send 'requested_action' then check it.